# TypeError: Received message 257:None is not bytes in azure-servicebus python sdk

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-python-sdk

after consuming some messages from azure servicebus queue, python sdk for azure-servicebus is failing with below error

```
socket.send() raised exception.
Unexpected error occurred (TypeError('Received message 257:None is not bytes')). Handler shutting down.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/aio/_base_handler_async.py", line 269, in _do_retryable_operation
    return await operation(**kwargs)
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/aio/_servicebus_receiver_async.py", line 410, in _receive
    receiving = await amqp_receive_client.do_work_async()
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/_pyamqp/aio/_client_async.py", line 357, in do_work_async
    return await self._client_run_async(**kwargs)
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/_pyamqp/aio/_client_async.py", line 753, in _client_run_async
    await self._connection.listen(wait=self._socket_timeout, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/_pyamqp/aio/_connection_async.py", line 798, in listen
    if await self._read_frame(wait=wait, **kwargs):
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/_pyamqp/aio/_connection_async.py", line 268, in _read_frame
    new_frame = await self._transport.receive_frame(timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/_pyamqp/aio/_transport_async.py", line 76, in receive_frame
    header, channel, payload = await asyncio.wait_for(
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 445, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result
    raise self._exception.with_traceback(self._exception_tb)
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 232, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/_pyamqp/aio/_transport_async.py", line 133, in read
    await self._read(payload_size, buffer=payload)
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/_pyamqp/aio/_transport_async.py", line 532, in _read
    data = await self.sock.receive_bytes()
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 281, in receive_bytes
    raise TypeError(f"Received message {msg.type}:{msg.data!r} is not bytes")
TypeError: Received message 257:None is not bytes
exception:Handler failed: Received message 257:None is not bytes.
```

below is the code using to fetch messages from queue

```
from azure.servicebus import TransportType
from azure.servicebus.aio import ServiceBusClient
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connection_string,
                                                            transport_type=TransportType.AmqpOverWebsocket,
                                                            max_lock_duration=180, logging_enable=True)
async with servicebus_client:
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name)
    async with receiver:
       messages = await receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=5000, max_wait_time=60)
```

python version 3.10 and azure-servicebus version 7.11.2